# i need help php css div and flash

Tags: php, css, flash, html

hello i wanted to include this flash clock on my header but it overlaps causing the existing header not being displayed. please refer to the image link thanks.

```
<?php 
echo "
  <p align=\"center\">
  <embed 
    title=\"Clock\" 
    src=\"http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/onlineclock.swf?ccolor=red\"quality=\"high\" 
    wmode=\"transparent\" bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" width=\"88\" 
    height=\"31\" align=\"middle\" allowScriptAccess=\"sameDomain\" 
    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" 
    pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" 
  />
  <br>\n";
?>
```

this is almost working but still interferring...

```
<?php echo "<div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 1;\"> <embed title=\"Clock\" src=\"http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/onlineclock.swf?ccolor=red\" quality=\"high\" wmode=\"transparent\"  width=\"88\" height=\"31\" align=\"middle\" allowScriptAccess=\"sameDomain\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" /><br>\n </div>\n";?>
```

Comment: What is your question, what doesn't work as desired?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "float"? Maybe add a screenshot of what you have, so we can see what the problem you are having looks like. Help us help you.

Comment: cant post image yet need more "reputations" :(

Comment: the header is workning fine already i just wanted to add that clock but i overlapped destryoing my header but the clock is appearing...

Comment: tried it with z-index in css?  why not posting a link to an image?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/beforen.png/

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/813/afterqr.png/

Comment: ok, so how do you want it to look like exactly

Comment: the clock should be on the afterqr.png is ok but it destroys the existing header below it.. also i created this but still interferring with the header that labels days/date of the week <?php
echo "<div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 1;\">   
<embed title=\"Clock\" src=\"http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/onlineclock.swf?ccolor=red\" quality=\"high\" wmode=\"transparent\"  width=\"88\" height=\"31\" align=\"middle\" allowScriptAccess=\"sameDomain\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" /><br>\n 
</div>\n";
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think you should use z-index in css style sheet (read css z-index if u dont know about it) by giving id's to both header and clock and then use z-index on these as suggested earlier by daniel.

Best of luck

Comment: how can i include the div tag in my script? the only thing that i knew is something like this echo "<div class=\"topBar\">\n";
echo "<font id=\"ur\" size=\"10\" face=\"Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif\" color=\"#DAD3B7\"></font>\n";
so since this is flash how can i add it in?

Comment: i was able to get it based from your input many thanks!  <?php
echo "<div style=\"position: absolute; z-index: 1; top:16px;\">   
<embed title=\"Clock\" src=\"http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/onlineclock.swf?ccolor=red\" quality=\"high\" wmode=\"transparent\"  width=\"80\" height=\"27\" align=\"middle\" allowScriptAccess=\"sameDomain\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" /><br>\n 
</div>\n";
?>